# How to call a function of a different class within another function

Tags: codeblocks

If I call the function
BasicDrawPane.Main();
within another function
orbit2Frame::OnMenuSettingsSelected(wxCommandEvent& event)
I get the error *expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token*.

If I call it using
BasicDrawPane::Main();
I get the error
*cannot call member function ‘void BasicDrawPane::Main()’ without object*.
If I try:

```
BasicDrawPane bdp;
bdp.Main();
```

I get: *no matching function for call to ‘BasicDrawPane::BasicDrawPane()’*

I'm new to both wxWigets and C++, and I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong for a few days. The above methods are generally what I've found on the internet, but they aren't working, so am I calling this function wrong, or is there something wrong somewhere else in the code?

I could post the rest of the code if needed, but it is fairly messy.

Thankyou :)

Comment: Why are you trying to call the `Main` function?

Comment: You should really show some minimal code, it's impossible to answer your questions without more information. Also, this has nothing to do with wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get: no matching function for call to ‘BasicDrawPane::BasicDrawPane()’

means that compiler cant find constructor for BasicDrawPane class.

Perhaps there is something wrong with class definition.